gdal ogr transform c++ swaps axis order x to y
This is example
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/ogr_spatialref.h"
#include <iostream>

void TransformBounds(double xmin, double ymin, double xmax, double ymax,
                     double &out_xmin, double &out_ymin, double &out_xmax, double &out_ymax) {
    OGRSpatialReference srcSRS, dstSRS;
    srcSRS.importFromEPSG(3857);  // Source CRS (EPSG:3857)
    dstSRS.importFromEPSG(4326);  // Destination CRS (EPSG:4326)

    OGRCoordinateTransformation *poCT;
    poCT = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&srcSRS, &dstSRS);

    if (poCT == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Transformation creation failed." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    double xMin = xmin;
    double yMin = ymin;
    double xMax = xmax;
    double yMax = ymax;

    // Transform min and max points
    if (poCT->Transform(1, &xMin, &yMin) && poCT->Transform(1, &xMax, &yMax)) {
        out_xmin = xMin;
        out_ymin = yMin;
        out_xmax = xMax;
        out_ymax = yMax;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Transformation failed." << std::endl;
    }

    OCTDestroyCoordinateTransformation(poCT);
}

int main() {
    double minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
    TransformBounds(-9551280, 5571610, -9505450, 5601390, minX, minY, maxX, maxY);

    std::cout << "minX: " << minX << ", minY: " << minY 
              << ", maxX: " << maxX << ", maxY: " << maxY << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

response is

minX: 44.6821, minY: -85.8006, maxX: 44.872, maxY: -85.3889

Here we can see the x and y coordinates swapped, but in the command line it works fine, am I doing anything wrong?

The axis order of 4326 is poorly defined, so you'll need to check exactly which axis order you are using

GDAL honours the axis order of the corresponding coordinate reference system. For EPSG:3857 the axis order is easting-northing, for EPSG:4326 latitude-longitude. The command line utility is using the "traditional GIS order" because of historical reasons. See https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html for more information.
